# Update IOS on Cisco CGS2520 Switch

Tags: cisco, switch, cisco-ios, os-upgrade-procedure

I need to update the IOS on a Cisco CGS2520 Switch. Not stacked, single switch

I have never done this before and I have a couple questions.

I do not have physical access to the switch.

Looking at the list of downloads for that switch

https://software.cisco.com/download/home/283090977/type/280805680/release/15.0.2-SE?releaseIndicator=DEFERRED

There are 4 options, which one would I want, how would I know?

```
IP SERVICES 
IP SERVICES WITH EXPRESS SETUP
LAN BASE
LAN BASE WITH EXPRESS SETUP
```

It says 15.2.7E2(MD) is the recommended. I am currently running 15.0(2)ED1.

Boot loader is Version 12.2(0.0.8)EY not sure what that is, does that need to be upgraded as well?

I have googled around and found the step to add the image via tftp, and install however:

1. Will the switch reset? Will I still be able to access it? Currently accessed via SSH through a VPN
2. If I enter the "reload in 20" command, and everything goes down, will the switch still reload in 20 minutes? Some of the articles I have read say I would need to wr mem and reboot the switch. Is there a failback procedure?

Comment: "_There are 4 options, which one would I want, how would I know?_" That depends on the services you need. You need to compare the features you want with those offered by the different licenses. In fact, you should know all that before deciding to upgrade the software (why you want to upgrade), and be familiar with the bug scrub of the code you want. Upgrading just to upgrade is not really something you want to do.

Comment: Removed the off-topic request for resouce recommendations.

Comment: @RonMaupin Is there a way I can tell what I am currently running from the 4 options? I need to upgrade because the IOS on the switch is showing multiple vulnerabilities, that according to Nessus can only be fixed via and IOS upgrade.

Comment: Show your license information from the CLI.

Comment: By the way, without looking at the bug scrub for your proposed version, you may not fix some vulnerabilities, and you may introduce more.

Comment: @RonMaupin How can I do that, from the CLI terminal I do not have "show license"?

Comment: That is in Enable mode, not Config mode.

Comment: It sounds like you should be working with Cisco TAC. No offense, but it sounds like you are in over your head.

Comment: @RonMaupin I know enough to be dangerous, I inherited this project, Mostly servers, however there is a firewall (non cisco) and 1 Cisco Switch, I managed to lock myself out of the switch the first day luckily I did not save the configuration, so I had the datacenter team reset it for me, cost $250. Now I have to remediate a couple vulnerabilities, recommendation is to upgrade the switch IOS. Never done that before and not looking to spend another $250 or more.

Comment: Just call Cisco TAC. They help with bugs and vulnerabilities.

Comment: Have you clicked the link at the top right of the CCO software page? (the link to the release notes) Read that. Seriously.